# How do I use the number range in regex matched groups in a loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to use the numbers in a regex find and run a loop using the first number as a starting point and the last number as the ending point and write some text using only javascript core objects, methods or functions.
Say I have an array of strings in the form `'<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">', '<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">' and so on..` and using this array I want to write something like below:
Expected output:

```
rid"4"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"5"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"6"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"7"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"8"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"9"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"15"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
rid"16"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
rid"17"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
```

Basically, it takes the number range from the array and uses every single number that fall in the range and write it in above mentioned fashion.
I've tried the below code:

```
var myString = ['<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">', '<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">'];
            var myRegexp = /(\d+)-(\d+)/g;
            my_arr = myRegexp.exec(myString);
            while (my_arr != null) {
                var a1 = my_arr[0];
                var xs = a1.split("-");
                var new1=xs[0];
                var new2=xs[1];
                for (var i=new1; i<=new2; i++){
                    console.log('rid"'+i+'"/'+myString[0]);
                }
                var a2 = my_arr[1];
                var ys = a2.split("-");
                var _new1=xs[0];
                var _new2=xs[1];
                for (var j=_new1; j<=_new2; j++){
                    console.log('rid"'+j+'"/'+myString[1]);
                }
                my_arr = myRegexp.exec(myString);
            }
```

But it returns

```
rid"4"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"5"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"6"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"7"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"8"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"9"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"4"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
rid"5"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
rid"6"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
rid"7"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
rid"8"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
rid"9"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
rid"15"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"16"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"17"/<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">
rid"15"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
rid"16"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
rid"17"/<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: @marvel308 the expected output is the first block of code in question. I've modified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to work

```js
var myString = ['<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">', '<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">', '<disp-formula id="deqn99-100">', '<disp-formula id="deqn999-1001">'];
var myRegexp = /(\d+)-(\d+)/g;
my_arr = myRegexp.exec(myString);
var idx = 0;
while (my_arr != null) {
    var a1 = my_arr[0];
    var xs = a1.split("-");
    var new1=parseInt(xs[0]);
    var new2=parseInt(xs[1]);
    for (var i=new1; i<=new2; i++){
        console.log('rid"'+i+'"/'+myString[idx]);
    }
    idx++;
    my_arr = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

The mistakes were

```
var a2 = my_arr[1];
```

this matched the 1st capturing group(i.e 4) and not the 2nd match

```
my_arr = myRegexp.exec(myString);
```

this would now move on to the next match and just print  myString[idx] over their

Now what did I change to make it work, if you refer to [this MDN blog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) you will see that this part

```
var a2 = my_arr[1];
var ys = a2.split("-");
var _new1=xs[0];
var _new2=xs[1];
for (var j=_new1; j<=_new2; j++){
    console.log('rid"'+j+'"/'+myString[1]);
}
```

is of no use so I removed it. Now we will move on to the next idx so I did

```
idx++
my_arr = myRegexp.exec(myString);
```

now my_arr will move on to the next match

Comment: thanks, one last thing, how do I use **document.write** to write those found items line by line instead of **console.log** ?

Comment: This doesn't work when there are string in the array like `<disp-formula id="deqn99-100">, <disp-formula id="deqn999-1001">`

Comment: what do you  mean array like ?

Comment: if `var myString = ['<disp-formula id="deqn4-9">', '<disp-formula id="deqn15-17">', '<disp-formula id="deqn99-100">', '<disp-formula id="deqn999-1001">'];` then the result is not showing `rid"99"/<disp-formula id="deqn99-100">
rid"100"/<disp-formula id="deqn99-100">
rid"999"/<disp-formula id="deqn999-1001">
rid"1000"/<disp-formula id="deqn999-1001">
rid"1001"/<disp-formula id="deqn999-1001">`

Comment: I edited my code to work now, I just added a parseInt() for new1 and new2